# How to use two Azure Directory simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have two directory AD1@company1.com and AD2@company2.com

AD1 has Application1 and
AD2 has Application2
AD1 has User1 whose email is User1@company1.com
AD2 has User2 whose email is User2@company2.com

How to authenticate my ASP.NET MVC application using both Active directory.
if user1 try login he should be authenticated by AD1 and if user2 try login he should be authenticated by AD2

Comment: You'll need to create 2 authentication providers (one for each company's AD)

Comment: I have 2 client id and tanent id but how to switch between them?

Answer (score 0):

A good option for your scenario would be to register your application as [multitenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) and create a service principal in the second tenant. The users will [sign in with their own organizational credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/), and the users can be an admin in the app without being an admin in the second tenant.

Illustration from the documentation of the application setup that has users from two tenants:

[image]

Another option is to add the users as guest users to the second tenant, but this setup can be a lot more costly since you would need to have license for all of these users.